# Top bar reputation notification off by amount of upvote on accepted answer

Tags: bug, top-bar, achievements-dialog

If there's already a duplicate of this, I apologize.. was unable to find it. I also don't have a picture, because I clicked the notification to make sure things were alright.  To the point though..

'Yesterday', someone up-voted an answer of mine, and of course, I got 10 rep for it.  Nothing wrong there.  Today, that answer was accepted, and I got the right amount... but for some reason, the top bar displayed this change of rep as +5, even though I had of course gotten +15.

This was encountered on Stack Overflow.

Is this a bug, or part of the design?

Comment: You had probably lost 10 rep (un-upvote or 5 downvotes, who knows) after the answer was upvoted and before it was accepted.

Comment: @3ventic I've pretty much been here all day, never saw a single downvote in my time line, or an un-upvote.

Comment: Site shouldn't matter since the + value shown is a net gain from all sites. (I had +98 from association bonus on stackapps because I had just before that been downvoted on Arqade.)

Comment: In your answers tab, click "deleted recent answers" link in the bottom. You will most likely see answer deleted today, which had one upvote. You have to click the link to the answer to see its score, there is a known bug in the "Deleted Recent Answers" page itself that does not show the correct answer scores.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - But if they don't show up in the rep drop down I guess the OP will need to do that on all sites as a consolidated total.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I haven't deleted any answers today, nor yesterday.

Comment: @Daedalus - Someone else may have deleted a question you participated in.

Comment: @Daedalus answers can be deleted in other ways, e.g. whole question got deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The screen is blank; sorry, should have mentioned that.(as in the 'recently deleted answers' screen).

Comment: Anyway, going through all my accounts right now to check that, though its likely going to be the same story, as SO and MSO are the only sites I've participated in.. everything else is visits or edits(one case of this, actually).

Comment: Also check the recently deleted questions, maybe question with two upvotes was deleted which also explains the -10.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nothing there either, and that applies to all accounts as well.

Comment: OK, so there's something weird going on... keep an open eye and take screenshots next time it happens. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I will next time it does, assuming it does.